# How to Count numbers of line, word and characters from Edittext field in Android

Tags: android, java-io

I am beginner, I want to make one simple application that will count number of lines, words and characters from whatever we have entered in Editext field. i want result like:

EditText : My name is abc.

Button CLick---->

Result:

No. of Words        : 4
No. of Characters   : 14
No. of Lines        : 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lines in edittext can vary depending on device....
for words:

```
char ch[]= new char[s.length()];      //in string especially we have to mention the () after length
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        ch[i]= s.charAt(i);
        if( ((i>0)&&(ch[i]!=' ')&&(ch[i-1]==' ')) || ((ch[0]!=' ')&&(i==0)) )
        c++;
    }
```

and for characters: `s.length()`

Answer (score 1):

First get the Edittext value.then do like as java word counter

```
EditText e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittextid);
String mytext=e1.getText().toString();
```

Apply  java code for **mytext**